# ssh still reporting old version after upgrading openssh-client and openssh-server

Tags: apt, ssh, openssh

Security Metrics are complaining our version of ssh is out of date.
If I run `ssh -V` I get this:

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

But if I run `dpkg -s openssh-client | grep '^Version:'` I get this:

```
Version: 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2
```

That version was released on March 9th 2021 and fixes all the security issues which Security metrics are complaining about.
I've tried using apt updgrade for openssh-client but it says I already have the latest version installed and shows me the 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2 version.
I also used `ssh -v localhost` to confirm that's also eporting the old version.

How can I get the system to use the latest versions of openssh-client and openssh-server which are installed?

Answer (score 0):

Your output seems to conclusively show that you ARE using the latest package for 20.04.

A Debian-based system can have only a single version of a package installed. In Ubuntu, newer versions *overwrite* older.

For your 20.04 system, http://packages.ubuntu.com comfirms that the newest `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` package version is 1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.2...which is what both your outputs say is running.

Perhaps the discrepancy that you are looking at is the date instead of the version number. The older date on `ssh -V` refers to the upstream version release, not the Ubuntu patch date.

Ubuntu LTS releases do not bump to the newest version of ssh -- that would break workflows. Instead, vulnerabilities (identified by a CVE) are patched by the Ubuntu Security Team, often using the upstream patch provided for exactly this purpose. **This is a standard and accepted industry practice**.

- Example: Ubuntu 18.04 uses ssh 7.6, fully patched.
- You can have the latest ssh by using the latest (non-LTS) version of Ubuntu.

Your security metric should be accordingly adjusted.